# Porting html2canavas-proxy for php

Tags: php, perl

Can someone help me proting this script: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas-proxy/blob/master/python/html2canvas.py to a php version?

i don't understand pearl, so it's very hard for me.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this is not a real question.

Comment: I don't understand 'pearl' either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that there is  a perl interface to google appengine, but you can use firefox :)

```
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

# The original line in the example
my $png = $mech->content_as_png();

# Method 1
my $png = $mech->element_as_png($mech->selector('html')); 

# Method 2
my $png = $mech->content_as_png(undef, 
                {left=>0,top=>0,width=>200, height=>200});
```